# html/php Directory file

Tags: php, html, url

I am trying to track the directory of a file in the APP of my company and I found this :

```
support/visitor/index.php?/LiveChat/Chat/Start
```

What I know is that if Directory  is `support/visitor/index.php`

Than the file `index.php` should reside in :

```
support
|_visitor
  |_index.php
```

What I know about interrogations in url is that they are used to pass parameters, `?name=John&iq=95` but what if they are passed in that way `?/LiveChat/Chat/Start` what does it mean ? it looks like a salad without dressing to me

Comment: Well all the URL rewritings are written in .htacces file from there you will know what `/LiveChat/Chat/Start` mean.

But in simple words we can say that there are 3 values passed in query string and these are `LiveChat` ,`Chat` and last one `Chat`.

Comment: Thank you that should have been written in the solution section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all the URL rewritings are written in `.htacces` file from there you will know what /LiveChat/Chat/Start mean.

But in simple words we can say that there are 3 values passed in query string and these are `LiveChat` ,`Chat` and last one `Start`.

Feel free to ask any questions... :)